# How to get Last Month Items via Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5, eloquent

I was using PDO to get the items from last one week or one month as shown in the below code. Now I am converting that code into Laravel. So, I want to know if there is the Eloquent way to implement the following query:

```
public function trendingAlbums($category=null,$order='views',$from=0,$limit=20,$term=null) {
    $cond = isset($category) ? "AND category_id IN ($category)" : '';
    if($term == 'month') {
        $cond .= "AND created_at BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE() ,INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AND CURRENT_DATE()";
    } elseif ($term =='week') {
        $cond .= "AND created_at BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE() ,INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND CURRENT_DATE()";
    }

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM view_albums WHERE 1 $cond ORDER BY $order DESC LIMIT :from, $limit";
    try {
        $q = $this->con->prepare($sql);
        isset($category) ? $q->bindValue(':category',$category,PDO::PARAM_STR) : '';
        $q->bindvalue(':from',$from,PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $q->execute();
    } catch (PDOException $ex) {
        return $this->errorhandler($ex->getmessage()); // displaying/hanlding actual error message
        //return $ex->getMessage();
    }
    $r= $q->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    return $r;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Carbon. It allows you to create dates easily like Carbon::today()->subWeeks(1) or Carbon::today()->subMonths(1).

Answer (score 2):

You can do it this way

```
$items = Item::where( DB::raw('MONTH(created_at)'), '=', date('n') )->get();
```

Comment: Very good answer. There's actually a [`whereMonth`](https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_whereMonth) method that does exactly the same thing but without he need to use `DB::raw`. You might want to include that in your answer.

Comment: actually it will return current month or some specific month items not last month(/last 30 day) items   while i need to return last one month or 30 day items ..